# Extjs MVC Global Store

Tags: extjs

I have an application built using extjs 6.2. I want to use single instance of the store with multiple grids and charts as the same data need to be displayed in different places. If I make new instance of the store I generate new request to fetch the data. How could I used single instance on multiple places.

Thanks,
Majid

Comment: Use the stores config on the application object.

Comment: Any particular example of accessing the application store in sub panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your store in the [view model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#cfg-stores) of your main view component:

```
stores: {
    mystore: {
        model: 'mymodel',
        autoLoad: true
    }
}
```

And then you can access it descendant components via [binding](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-bind):

```
xtype: 'grid',
bind: {
    store: '{mystore}'
}
```

Or you can create the store anywhere in your application (before it is required by the components) assigning it a [storeId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-storeId).

> Unique identifier for this store. If present, this Store will be
>   registered with the Ext.data.StoreManager, making it easy to reuse
>   elsewhere.

```
Ext.create('App.store.MyStore', {storeId: 'myStore'});
```

And then access it using [Ext.getStore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-getStore):

```
Ext.getStore('myStore')
```

Or even specifying only the the `storeId` for the component's store config, if they accept this (the grids do):

```
xtype: 'grid',
store: 'myStore'
```

Comment: Thanks for detail solution.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers